Issue with Python Flask App Deployment to Azure App Service During Zip Deployment
I'm facing an issue with deploying my Python Flask app to Azure App Service(Python 3.9) using zip deployment. Below are the details:
Directory structure:
.
|---app.py    
|---requirements.txt

Working Code:
app.py:
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello, Azure!--1"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)

requirements.txt:
Flask==3.1.0

Non-Working Code:
app.py:
from flask import Flask
import openai

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello, Azure!--2"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)

requirements.txt:
Flask==3.1.0
openai==1.57.1

Steps for deploying:
Create zip:

Open the directory in file explorer
Select the above files (app.py and requirements.txt)
Right click on file app.py
Compress to -> ZIP File

Command to deploy into Azure app service:
curl -k -v -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/zip' -u "<$app_service_user>:<60character_length_userPWD>" --data-binary @app.zip https://<appservicename>.scm.dev001.ase.frk.com/api/zipdeploy

Error in the API log stream:
Site's appCommandLine: gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 app:app
Launching oryx with: create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -virtualEnvName antenv -defaultApp /opt/defaultsite -userStartupCommand 'gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 app:app'
Could not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
Build Operation ID: c9b33d68-8d6d-4326-9b08-257fe923d135
Oryx Version: 0.2.20240619.2, Commit: cf006407a02b225f59dccd677986973c7889aa50, ReleaseTagName: 20240619.2
Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
WARNING: Could not find virtual environment directory /home/site/wwwroot/antenv.
WARNING: Could not find package directory /home/site/wwwroot/__oryx_packages__.



Booting worker with pid: 1075
[1075] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/python/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
  worker.init_process()
File "/opt/python/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
  self.load_wsgi()
File "/opt/python/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
  self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
File "/opt/python/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
  self.callable = self.load()
File "/opt/python/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
  return self.load_wsgiapp()
File "/opt/python/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
  return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
File "/opt/python/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 371, in import_app
  mod = importlib.import_module(module)
File "/opt/python/3.9.19/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/site/wwwroot/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    import openai
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai'
[1075] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1075)
[1064] [ERROR] Worker (pid:1075) exited with code 3
[1064] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
[1064] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

I've verified that the code works locally, but it fails when deployed to Azure App Service. Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Can you share the folder structure or the link you are referring to if any?

How are you deploying your code? @chiru

Update the body with folder structure and the command using for zipdeploy - @IkhtesamAfrin

Can you try the below given way and also refer the doc I have added in my answer?

The deployment is proceeding through the VS Web deployment. However, the Zip deployment is still having issues.

I have referred to the documentation available for creating and deploying sample Flask application and cloned it locally in vs code.
I also have used the same code provided by you a long with Flask and openai modules in requirements.txt file.
Then, I created the virtual environment and activated it using below commands.
py -m venv .venv 
.venv\scripts\activate

Installed the dependencies using pip install -r requirements.txt command.
It worked for me locally alike you.

I have created a Linux Azure App service with runtime as python 3.9.
Then, I deployed the code using vs code.


I am able to access the application successfully.

You could be getting this issue due to improper deployment. As its showing python could not find virtual environment directory /home/site/wwwroot/antenv warning for you which means either virtual environment is not created or it can't find it. So, you can deploy using any other alternate way like vs code or cli command.

The deployment is proceeding through the VS Web deployment. However, the Zip deployment is still having issues.

Are you trying as per my way?

Yes Afrin. As per your way we tried deploying through vs code and found it is working. And We want to implement this deployment in a CI/CD. That’s where we are using the zipDeploy mechanism. Can you suggest what could be the debugging approach to identify zipDeploy issue when vscode deployment is working fine?

Can you refer this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=flask%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli%2Czip-deploy%2Cdeploy-instructions-azportal%2Cterminal-bash%2Cdeploy-instructions-zip-azcli#deploy-your-application-code-to-azure wherein deploy using zip file is illustrated

Are you talking about GitHub Actions CI/CD or DevOps?

Yes, I'm referring to the CI/CD happening through Bamboo. We are deploying zip files using the curl command.
'curl -k -v -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/zip' -u "<$app_service_user>:<60character_length_userPWD>" --data-binary @app.zip https://.scm.dev001.ase.frk.com/api/zipdeploy'.
Typically, after running this command, a virtual env 'antenv' is created on the app service, & all of the modules listed in requirements.txt are installed on the virtual env.
However, the virtual env is no longer being built & displays the error shown above. That is where I am stuck.

Yes, its because virtual environment is getting created properly. Navigate to /home/site/wwwroot and execute python3 -m venv antenv , then activate the virtual environment by executing source antenv/bin/activate  command and then execute pip install -r requirements.txt.
